# Use cosine rule to determine the length of a side of a triangle. Cannot replicate textbook solution

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Given a triangle of lengths $4$, $5$ and $x$, where the sides of length $4$ and $5$ meet at an angle of $60^{\circ}$, I must calculate the length of side $x$.

[image]

The cosine rule is: $$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc\cos(\alpha)$$

So, applying to my problem:
$$\begin{align}
a^2&=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(\alpha) \\
x^2&=4^2+5^2-2(4)(5)(\cos(60^{\circ})) \\
x^2&=16+25-40\cos(60^{\circ}) \\
x^2&=41-40\cos(60^{\circ}) \\
x^2&=41-40(0.9524) \\
x^2&=41-38.1 \\
x^2&=2.9 \\
x&=\sqrt{2.9}
\end{align}$$

The textbook solution says I should arrive at $x = \sqrt{21}$, not $x=\sqrt{2.9}$. The textbook does not provide working to the solution, only the final answer.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\cos 60°=0.5$, you need to study the unit circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\cos(60^o)=0.5$ maybe you mixed radians ($60^o=1/3\pi$) with degrees on your calculator?

Comment: Oh. I used Google Calculator in my browser: https://www.google.com/search?q=online+calculator, I typed the COS button then 60. Thanks for letting me know. Are you able to get 0.5 with Googles online calculator somehow?

Comment: Hm. I just openned R application too and typed cos(60) which gave me the same result as Google calculator

Comment: @DougFir: In Google calculator, click "Rad" in the left top corner, that will switch it to degrees.

Comment: @Vasya thank you, that allowed me to replicate the result 0.5.

Comment: @DougFir $\cos 60\text{rad}\approx -0.9524$, so there's a sign issue too. A negative cosine is obtained for obtuse angles.